# How to describe and visualize continued changed data from mongoDB using pandas

Tags: python, mongodb, pandas, flask

I'm setting up an API using Flask, and add some JSON post using postman to be transferred to mongoDB database.

Then I had to visualize statistics of the real time data from the database into lets say `data_analysis_script.py`, which means if I post some JSON from postman, the statistics should be changed since the data had been added.

Any suggestion about function or library I could use further in script for showing the data statistics ?

I had tried using manager which could run both app.run() and the code, but not print the code

API code

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request
from flask_pymongo import PyMongo
import pandas as pd

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config['MONGO_DBNAME'] = 'db'
app.config['MONGO_URI'] = 'mongodb://localhost:8000/db'

mongo = PyMongo(app)

@app.route('/stocks', methods=['GET'])
def get_all_stocks():
  stocks = mongo.db.stocks
  output = []
  for i in stocks.find():
    output.append({'name' : i['name'], 'item' : i['item']})
  return jsonify({'Here yours' : output})

@app.route('/add', methods=['POST'])
def add_stocks():
  stocks = mongo.db.stocks
  name = request.json['name']
  item = request.json['item']
  item_id = stocks.insert({'name': name, 'item': item})
  new_stocks = stocks.find_one({'_id': stocks_id })
  output = {'name' : new_stocks['name'], 'item' : new_stocks['item']}
  return jsonify({'Here yours' : output})

@app.route('/stocks/', methods=['GET'])
def get_one_stocks(name):
  stocks = mongo.db.stocks
  c = stocks.find_one({'name' : name})
  if s:
    output = {'name' : c['name'], 'item' : c['item']}
  else:
    output = "Nothing"
  return jsonify({'Here yours' : output})

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

I expect the data visualization and statistics changed when there is a JSON entry

Comment: Hi, what you are looking for is a *change data capture*. In mongo it is called [change stream](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/changeStreams/).

Comment: Right @MarkusRother thanks, I had already got a visual on it and let me try